# Share a Harddisk between two Windows Hosts on ESXi

Tags: windows, esxi, local-storage, vmdk

is it possible to share a VMDK between two Windows Hosts running on ESXi? I don't want to share the disk via CIFS because one windows machine acts as a VPN-Client where the VPN-Client-Software is blocking the network completely and I am not able to mount a disk via network.
Just to make it clear: I have 2 windows VMs running on ESXi (Win1 and Win2) and I want to have the same harddisk accessible from both VMs (not the system drive of cause!). When I put a file on that drive from Win1 it should be accessible from Win2, even without a working network connection.

Answer (score 2):

There ist a post on Experts Exchange:

`The key is to use virtual scsi bus sharing! which turns a vmdk, into shared disk between VMs.`

refering to a VMWare whitepaper: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-50-mscs-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a normal NTFS volume with two Windows computers - you need a cluster aware filesystem to do that.

So you'll need to dismount the volume from one computer before mounting it on the other computer.